# Get the value from a textbox and set it into another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I have 5 text boxes and a button. One of those text boxes is for entering text, and another is to receive value from the first one.

I want to create a loop to check every time I put something in the first text box so it shall check if there is an available text box.

```
<input id="inputtext" type="text" name="pass" placeholder="input text" onchange="langd()" />
<input class="txt" id="Text8" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text9" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text10" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text11" type="text" />
<input id="btnLaggTill" type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit"
       value="Lägg till" onclick="langd(); return false;">
```

```
function langd() {
var txt = $("#inputtext").val();
    if (document.getElementById("Text8") != "") {
        $("#Text8").val(txt);
        document.getElementById("Text8").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
   else if (document.getElementById("Text9") != "") {
        $("#Text9").val(txt);
        document.getElementById("Text9").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
   else if (document.getElementById("Text10") != "") {
        $("#Text10").val(txt);
        document.getElementById("Text10").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
   else if (document.getElementById("Text11") != "") {
        $("#Text11").val(txt);
        document.getElementById("Text11").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

Comment: show your html too..

Comment: <input id="inputtext" type="text" name="pass" placeholder="input text">  <input class="txt" id="Text8" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text9" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text10" type="text" />
<input class="txt" id="Text11" type="text" />   <input id="btnLaggTill" type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Lägg till" onclick="langd(); return false;">

Comment: Working fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Laa4Ln50/)** What is the problem you are facing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

HTML:

```
<form class="my-form">
    <input id="inputtext" type="text" name="pass" placeholder="input text">
    <input class="txt" id="Text8" type="text" />
    <input class="txt" id="Text9" type="text" />
    <input class="txt" id="Text10" type="text" />
    <input class="txt" id="Text11" type="text" />
    <input id="btnLaggTill" type="submit" name="login" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Lägg till">
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.my-form', function(){
    var txt = $('#inputtext').val();
    $(".txt:first").val(txt).removeClass('txt');
    return false;
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trpfyc66/)

Comment: @MiladFrancis No problem. If you need the `txt` class for styling you can add another class and remove that when needed. Also, you may wish to add the class again if the user clears the input, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a listener:

```
$("#inputtext").keyup(function() {
   langd();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set a function to the onChange to those textboxes?

```
<input id="txt_Search" type="text" onchange="Call()" />
<script>
function Call()
{
     ...
}

</script>
```

Comment: no I had not tested it but now that I have tested so I always get the value in the first text box